# How to reference a column

Tags: sql

How to reference a column in another table to a column In another table without using foreign key i.e for example I have a table named users inside users a column with a primary key named user_id, in another table i have a column named seller_id so this seller_id would be the same as the user_id.

Comment: You have noted a number of different sql types in your question.  The answer will be different depending on which one you are actually using.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: As you've tagged 3 completely different RDBMS system (one of which has been out of support for 3 years) I have removed the tags and added the *generic* sql tag. I suggestm, however, you retag the RDBMS you are really using and then show your attempts or explain what about the documentation you don't understand (MySQL, Postgresql and SQL Server are all well documented).

Comment: to add to @Larnu 's comment, Topicstarter you need to come with a example and expected results as more or less required by the [helpcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).. We simply can't help you without.. Also you should not be using stackoverflow  as a excuse into not having to research dig yourself in the RDMS manual(s) but fair enough you can't know (or understand)  everything but your question does not have any proof of a attempted search or research yourself..

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table named users inside users a column with a primary key named user_id,
>
> in another table i have a column named seller_id so this seller_id would be the same as the user_id.

You could use JOIN

```
select  u.*, t.*
from users u
inner join another_table t on t.seller_id  = u.user_id
```